# JArray Content become only [] when returns to Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core web api endpoint that returns the below class

```
public class CommonApiResponse
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
        public string Message { get; set; } = "Sucess";
        public object? Content { get; set; }
    }
```

then i have the below method that return a dynamic json

```
public async Task<CommonApiResponse> GetMasterDataPost(MasterDataApiModel param)
        {
            var result = new CommonApiResponse();

            try
            {
                var masterData = await MasterDataAPI.GetMasterDataPost(param); 
                //example: [{"PLANT":2100},{"PLANT":2200},{"PLANT":2210},{"PLANT":2300},{"PLANT":2310},{"PLANT":2320},{"PLANT":2400},{"PLANT":2600},{"PLANT":3100},{"PLANT":3300},{"PLANT":4200},{"PLANT":8000}]

                JArray jsonResponse = JArray.Parse(masterData);

                result.Content = jsonResponse;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Content of the JArray
[jarray result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi6Jf.png)

then below is how i return the result to client side

```
[HttpPost("GetMasterDataPost")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMasterDataPost(MasterDataApiModel param)
        {
            var result = await _masterDataBusiness.GetMasterDataPost(param);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

but the content will always just returns me empty brackets []
[result from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it4sf.png)

Anyone know what might be the problem?

rather than JArray
I tried to make it as a Dynamic
`dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(masterData);`

and tried to make the class property itself from object to dynamic

but both doesn't work

Comment: I don't get the reason because you're using the JArray instead of straight assigning the `masterData` to the `Content` property.

Comment: @MarioVernari the masterData is a json string, but i want to return the result as json

Comment: ```JArray.Parse(masterData)``` seems like a reasonable approach. If you are certain the ```masterData``` string is valid JSON, assigning it directly to ```result.Content``` should work fine, since the serialization process should take care of converting the string to a proper JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end, i just return the raw string from `masterData`
and from the client side, i use `JSON.parse` to convert the string to Json,
now everything works as expected

thanks for all the help